# JQuery: can I nest these conditional statements?

Tags: jquery

```
$( object1 ).click( function() {
    // do this to object 1
    // then perform function "batch"
}

$( object2 ).click( function() {
    // do this to object 2
    // then perform function "batch"
}

$( object3 ).click( function() {
    // do this to object 3
    // then perform function "batch"
}
```

This is how I have my script right now and it works great but the "batch" function, which is to be performed no matter which object is clicked is declared 3 times as you can see. Is this the most efficient way of writing this code or can I use if/else or even switch statements?

Comment: Isn't `batch` declared once and called from multiple (3) places? Isn't that one of the key reasons to use named functions. I like it the way you have it, simple, clear and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function and pass it to the click handler.

```
function batch(ev){
    // Do something
}

$( object1 ).click(batch);
```

Comment: Your example is missing the "do stuff to object 1". And what is the purpose of "ev"?

Comment: The function can do stuff to the object, no? ev is the event that is passed by the callback handler.